# Play video in Tizen web app

Tags: html, tizen, tizen-tv

I have a Tizen web application. On one page there is a `video` html tag. It plays video from m3u8 format, using hls well, but if I set as a source a video file - it is not played. Here is the code:

```html
<video id="video"
            src="http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/q1fx20VZ-52qL9xLP.mp4"  preload="auto" controls  loop autoplay>
       </video>
```

In browser it works fine. Seems that Tizen just ignores it for some reason. How can I play video from file?

Comment: Add Internet privilege and Domain Access policies in the config.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below privilege and policy in your ***config.xml***.

```
<tizen:privilege name="tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```